# How to render static vaweform with AudioContext object

Tags: javascript, audio

I found so much examples to render audio-vaweform in real time. But I need just have a STATIC vaweform on Canvas. Is anybody know the way to do this? Maybe by using AudioContext object or createAnalyser() method?

Comment: when you say "static", you mean that the audio is a periodic signal and you want to render it so the wave doesn't "move" across the canvas?

Comment: or do you want to render the entire waveform for an offline source (not real-time) ?

Comment: Yep. I want wave to NOT move. It should be once generated and not to be changed in time. But the audio-file should be taken from local machine, not from Internet. And, that is important, all this things should done with <canvas>. Can you help?

Comment: When I said "offline" I mean not real-time. I mean, you want to read the audio file, create the waveform, and show it. Not to animate it as you play the file. Correct?

Comment: I'll answer your question, but in the meantime, edit it so it's more clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the audio data is to load the audio file to an ArrayBuffer with the File API (for now I'll assume you know how to do that) and then pass that to the [decodeAudioData](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioContext-decodeAudioData-Promise-AudioBuffer--ArrayBuffer-audioData-DecodeSuccessCallback-successCallback-DecodeErrorCallback-errorCallback) method of the Web Audio API.

You'll get a Promise for an AudioBuffer containing the decoded audio samples, i.e. the waveform. Once the promise resolves, all you have to do is iterate over the AudioBuffer and draw the values (or an average of the values over some time, since you may not want 44k pixels per second ;)) to your canvas.

Need more detail about any part of this?